# Bash Script Echo -n

Tags: bash, echo

I am writing a bash script, and I want to echo a string, but without a newline automatically added to the end. Reading the man page it says the flag is `-n`.

The problem is, when I do:

```
echo -n "My string is here"
```

The output in the bash script is:

```
-n My string is here
```

Any idea why the `-n` flag is being outputted instead of processed.

Comment: Which distro are you using?

Comment: :) LOL, on CentOS it works, but on OSx it does not. We are fine though, since its going to run on CentOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the shell you are using with:

```
echo $0
```

If it is `/bin/sh`, change to `/bin/bash` with `chsh` and try again.

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071106192548833

Comment: This'll change your interactive shell, but the shell used for scripts is determined by the shebang line at the beginning of the script (e.g. `#!/bin/sh`).

Answer (score 1):

Works on CentOS, but appears that OSX does not like the -n flag.

Comment: That's weird. I have several scripts on OS X Lion and Snow Leopard that use `echo -n` successfully.

Comment: It depends on which shell is running the script, usually dictated by the #! on the first line. If you explicitly ask for bash (`#!/bin/bash`) or some other shell that definitely supports the option then `echo -n`. On some systems the shell that `/bin/sh` represents *is* Bash or similar, but it could be something very simple that only implements the minimum functionality required to be POSIX compliant (and this doesn't include the  `-n` option for `echo`).

Comment: It also depends on the version of OS X (and hence bash) -- 10.4 understands `-n` just fine, but 10.5.0 doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`echo` is weirdly inconsistent between versions -- different versions of /bin/echo, as well as the builtin versions in various shells (even different versions of the same shell).  Some versions understand options (like `-n`), some versions understand escape sequences within the string (end with `"\c"` to skip the newline).  Some versions use a weird mix of the two.

If you want consistent behavior, avoid `echo` and use `printf` instead.  It's a little more complicated, but it's much more predictable:

```
printf "%s" "My string is here"
```